# Why is jQuery not loading in my Rails 3.2.3 app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Up until yesterday jQuery was loading just fine in my Rails app. I was playing around with getting the debugger/ruby-debug gem installed. As you are probably aware there are issues with the debugger gem in Rails 3 and I was unsuccessful in getting the dependancies installe so I removed the gems from my Gemfile. Since then when loading my site jQuery is not loading. These are the messages I see in console:

```
assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1:377Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
bootstrap-transition.js:24Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
bootstrap.js:3Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
welcome:210Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

And here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

If I load jQuery explicitly in layouts/application.html.erb, like so, it works:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to resolve this and get jQuery loading again? Looking in .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts I can see jquery.js and jquery.min.js are still there.

Comment: Do you still have the `gem 'jquery-rails'` line in your gemfile?

Comment: Sure do. Even did a gem install 'jquery-rails' successfully.

Comment: Did you try putting the jquery libs in app/assets/javascripts folder?

Comment: No. I never had to before. jQuery is included with a new Rails app as far as I know. Anyway, that's essentially what I'm doing in my snippet above, but I'm using a CDN instead of a local lib. Obviously for production I would have used a local lib as well for fall back, but this was just a test.

Comment: You must be having some sort of conflict with your JS files. Try reordering your tree and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks @Djj. Re-ordering my application.js tree seems to have resolved the issue. Here is my revised tree:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.placeholder
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was due to asynchronously loading the javascript file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", :async => true %>
```

Switching back to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

solved the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. I would like to take advantage of async though, any idea why it was causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

After a long time spent , this solved my problem with the error.

Make sure that Jquery is loaded only once.

Include `gem 'jquery-rails'`  in Gemfile and do `$ bundle install`

Make sure to include these in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

The syntax when wrong like  `// require jquery` leads to not loading jquery.

If everything is included right, the page source of your html file must show all the source files included.

For me, I had a problem because I was explicitly loading the jquery plugin sources from google in application.html.erb under app/views/layouts apart from requiring it in application.js file under app/assets/javascript. This caused jquery to be defined again and few errors like `placeholder()` not defined, `oApi` not defined for `null` would pop up.