# Show/Hide Text Field Based on Select Box Selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a simple form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :source, "How did you find out about us?", :class => "control-label" %>
  <%= f.select(:source, options_for_select([['--  Please select  --',nil],['Source 1','Source 1'], ['Source 2','Source 2'], ['Other','Other']])) %>

  <%= f.label :source_other, "Specify Other Source" %>
  <%= f.text_field :source_other %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to learn how to use JQuery to only show the "source_other" text field when the value "Other" is selected from the "source" field. From what I've seen online, it looks like I need to use something like this:

```
$("#source").change(function() {
  if ($("#source").val()=="Other")
    $("#source_other").show();
  else
    $("#source_other").hide();
});
```

However, I am not quite understanding how to integrate the JQuery with my form. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**Updated:**

Here is the resulting html snippet:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
  <label class="control-label" for="user_lead_source">How did you find out about us?</label>
  <select id="user_source" name="user[source]"><option value="">--  Please select  --</option>
    <option value="Source 1">Source 1</option>
    <option value="Source 2">Source 2</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <label for="user_source_other">Specify Other Source</label>
  <input id="user_source_other" name="user[source_other]" size="30" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: please show output html as browser sees it.  WHat do you mean by `integrate`?

Comment: By `integrate`, I mean - where do I put the JQuery code, and what else do I need to do in order to trigger it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suspecting that your server code doesn't generate an ID for the element, in which case your selectors are looking for elements with ID's that don't exist

If that is the case either add an ID with your server code so your jQuery ID selectors will work or use `name=` selectors

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="source"]').change(function() {
      $('input[name="source_other"]').toggle(  $(this).val()=="Other" );

    });
});
```

As long as jQuery code is wrapped in `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){});` which is shorthand for same, you can place it anywhere in page in a script tag so long as it is after after jQuery library has loaded . Or you can put it in extrnal file that loads after jQuery

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like Rails adds a prefix to the input name "[User]". Should I use a wildcard character or something like that - to make sure I'm referencing the right input name in the JQuery code?

Comment: OK...looks like rails adds the ID so original code should work

Comment: I've used the following code in my View, but it still isn't working right. What else am I missing?: `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $("#user_source").change(function() { if ($("#user_source").val()=="Other") $("#user_source_other").show(); else $("#user_source_other").hide(); }); }); </script>`

Comment: have you inclded jQuery? Are there any script errors in browser console? Code looks fine. Also if you have a live page I could take a look

Comment: Ok. I think I found something out. Apparently, the order matters for the require statements in the application.js file. I originally had the `require jquery` statement first. When I switch the order to have the `require jquery_ujs` statement first, the code starts working. Here is the order that works now:

`//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .`

I got this hint from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553343/why-is-jquery-not-loading-in-my-rails-3-2-3-app

Comment: With the application.js requirements ordered correctly, and the script now working - I realized what I really wanted was to show/hide a `div` rather than the actual form field. To accomplish this, the following code works:

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#other_source').hide();
  $("#user_source").change(function() {
    if ($("#user_source").val()=="Other")
      $("#other_source").show();
    else
      $("#other_source").hide();
  });  
});
</script>`

Comment: that order seems unintuitive...jQuery has to load before you can use it's functions, so it seems you have to call them in reverse in your require statments

Comment: Strange... after changing the load order of the require statements in the application.js file, it caused my session#destroy route to no longer work. So, I changed the load order back to the way it was to begin with - and now everything works. I'm not sure what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 $("#source") with $("#user_source")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).on("change", "#user_source", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value === "Other"){
      $("#source_other").show();
    }else{
      $("#source_other").hide();
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$("#user_source")` instead!

Rails adds the model name before the attribute. Then it should hide/show `$("#user_source_other")` element.

Moreover, you must wrap this jQuery JS code in `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){});` as charlietfl answered before.