# Rails how to create f.select element with optional text entry field (data persists)

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried dozens of different ways to accomplish this, and have not come close. NOT a 'combo box," in other words I'm not looking for a fancy autocomplete using existing   elements.  I need a text field independent of the  elements, but residing in the same drop-down menu --and when you enter a string value it needs to persist on form submit. Like this: 
[image: dropdown with optional text entry field enabled]

First of all, is there a name for this (like there is for 'combo box?'), and second, how is this accomplished? I've tried combo boxes, but of course the typed-in text is not saved.  I've tried .toggle, showing and hiding two divs (one with a f.select, one with f.text_field) but the text field will not save.  I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: The toggle sounds like it would work.  Are they the same name in the form?  If so, make sure the select is disabled when you show the text box.

Comment: Yes they're the same name in the form.  So I would be toggling the html attribute disabled: true? (or false?) (html disabled=true, in Rails, disabled: true or disabled: => true)

Comment: You'd be doing this in javascript, check out some other examples about how to do that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924277/show-hide-text-field-based-on-select-box-selection